# Convention for setPositiveButton for a dialog with only an Ok button?

Tags: android-layout

Is there a hard rule where setPositiveButton should be for the ok button? For example I am working on an app where I have a dialog popup which only shows the user a message with a OK button to dismiss the dialog, is it wrong to use Neutral or negative in this situation or does it depend on the content of the message?

For example I have a dialog which shows the user an error such as

The username has already been taken.
Ok button - setNegativeButton

Another where it is just for information

The color blue means the timeslot is available 
Ok button - setPositiveButton

Am I doing this right?

Comment: Technically you should use neutral for ok since it is a neutral answer, however I mostly just choose positive to position the ok button on the right side of the dialog. Beside the different callbacks the buttons will be positioned differently at the bottom of the dialog depending on if you choose positive, neutral or negative. Aside from that it doesn't really matter. You should always pick what's appropriate for the button, positive for yes, negative for no. Ok is an edge case and in my opinion positive and neutral are fine.

Comment: I don't think so, it is just matter of position of buttons they are placed. There is no such rule or code for using buttons, as per my knowledge.